# Computer Science (Database/ Data Mining) Conference Evaluation

Tags: publications

Can you tell me whether COSN (http://cosn.acm.org/2014/index.html) is a good conference? Its a new conference introduced by ACM with a strong PC committee. Last year, the acceptance rate was around 16%. I have recently finished a manuscript that I would like to try in either COSN, or WISE (http://delab.csd.auth.gr/wise2014/) which is an established rank A conference. Can you tell me which one will be a better venue in terms of exposure/visibility? My manuscript is on social network mining which is within the scope of both conferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the names I recognize on the program committee, yes, it's probably a good conference.

As for which conference will given you better visiblity: Neither!  The two conferences attract slightly different audiences.  Which audience do you want to impress more? Which audience (extrapolating from PC members and last year's accetd authors) are you more likely to draw recommendation letters and future colleagues from? Which conference looks like more like your "tribe"? Send it there.

And then put a copy on your web page.

Also: Ask your advisor.